# method setText(String) in the type Part is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, string, methods, settext

I have to develop one java application.

Here i got the below error:

**The method setText(String) in the type Part is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)**

Here i have to send the retrievedUserName,retrievedPassword to my mail via settext.
How can i call the above 2 string value in settext method.please help me.whats wrong in my code.

This is my code:

```
      public class SendMail {
      public String authentication(String Product,String Cost){
      String retrievedUserName = "";
      String retrievedPassword = "";
      String retrievedEmail = "";
      String status = "";
      try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");

      PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT xcart_products.product,xcart_products.list_price,xcart_customers.email FROM xcart_products,xcart_customers WHERE product = '"+Product+"'");
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
      while(result.next()){
       retrievedUserName = result.getString("list_price");
       retrievedPassword = result.getString("product");
       retrievedEmail = result.getString("email");
            }
          if(retrievedPassword.equals(Product)){
       status = "The product name is send to your email";
        Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
         props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxx@gmail.com","4242vfgDF!");
                        }
                    });
                   try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@gmail.com"));
         message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("demo@gamil.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Friends This is your product name and price"+
                    retrievedPassword,retrievedUserName);

        Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the charset. I also use setContent, but I suppose setText would work the same way. Try replacing your setText call with this:

```
 message.setContent("Dear Friends This is your product name and price "+
                     retrievedPassword+retrievedUserName, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you wouldn't mind up-voting my answer I would really appreciate it. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Getting no effect of " \n" while using setContent() .i have to need fistline retrievedPassword,have to need 2nd line retrievedUserName.so i have used below code.but it is not work for me. message.setContent("This is your product name"+
                retrievedPassword +"\nThis is your price"+ retrievedUserName, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: Hi danL I introduced "<br></br>" instead of "\n" and it is working. 
I want to know if you have a better solution to this problem.

Comment: It uses html so replace \n with <br /> Edit: Using the short-hand tag would save space so instead of <br></br> just use <br />

Comment: No problem. I would really appreciate it if you voted up my answer. Just click the ^ button beside my answer. I need to get all the reputation I can! Thanks!